# React recursion - can't get correct value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, recursion

I'm having Array of Objects named `items`. Each Object looks like this

```
interface IItem {
 id: string;
 title: string;
 items: IItem[] | null
}
```

So I'm doing recursion, as in

parent component:

```
        {items?.map((folder, index) => (
          <Item
            onClick={(event) => {
              event.stopPropagation();
              event.preventDefault();
              console.log(
                event.target.innerHTML,
                folder.id,
                folder.title
              );
            }}
            key={folder.id}
            data={folder}
          />
        ))}
```

While`Item` component looks like this:

```
const nestedItems =
    data.items
      ? data.items.map((item, index) => (
          <Item
            onClick={onClick}
            key={item.id}
            data={item}
          />
        ))
      : null;

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        <Typography>
          {data.title} {data.id}
        </Typography>
      </button>
      <div>{nestedItems}</div>
    </div>
```

Html output and whats rendered in browser looks correct,
but when I try to get `{id}, or {title}` from item in `parent` component
the output of any click which has parent doesn't log it's own id, but it's parent id.
The strange thing is that `console.log` from above on any "not first level items" looks like this:

`event.target.innerHTML` - correct value
`folder.id, folder.title` - has parent ? parent `id` value : it's own `id` value

So I'm not really sure what's happening and where is the catch :/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only define `onClick` for each of the root-level `Item`s and then within the `Item` component you just pass the `onClick` prop to the child. Thus every child has the same `onClick` function as its parent.

To fix this you can change `onClick` to be more generic by accepting data (the `id` and/or other information) rather than having data curried into it. This way the `onClick` function passed to the `Item` works for any item, but the `onClick` function passed to the button within each `Item` is unique to that item.

For example:

Parent component:

```
{items?.map((folder, index) => (
    <Item
      onClick={(event, clickedFolder) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(
          event.target.innerHTML,
          clickedFolder.id,
          clickedFolder.title
        );
      }}
      key={folder.id}
      data={folder}
    />
))}
```

`Item` component:

```
const nestedItems =
  data.items
    ? data.items.map((item, index) => (
        <Item
          onClick={onClick}
          key={item.id}
          data={item}
        />
      ))
    : null;

return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={event => onClick(event, data)}>
      <Typography>
        {data.title} {data.id}
      </Typography>
    </button>
    <div>{nestedItems}</div>
  </div>
)
```